# Chord-building patterns

Tags: terminology, chord-theory

The usual pattern for building chords, given a heptatonic scale with steps I, II, III, IV... VII, is to take the notes at position n, n+2 and n+4. With n=I this means we would have notes at steps I, III and V.

What is this chord-building pattern called?

Are there other similar patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just called Tertian harmony. There are other harmonies out there such as Secundal harmony which is built from seconds, Quartal harmony which is built from fourths, and Qunital harmony which is built from 5ths. Other methods of build harmony such as building in 6th and 7ths are possible, but typically are viewed as a diffrent way of looking at Tertian and Secundal harmony respectively.

Comment: I can see that building on 6ths is like a double tertian, but 7ths as secundal?

Comment: @Tim Let's put it this way if you build up  major seconds from C and have C, D, E vs building down major seconds from E and having E, D, C. They create similar structures, just the distance between the notes is greater. Even quintal is recognized as quartal sometimes due to this.

Comment: It's that 'rule of 9' probably - maj7 = invert of m2, I guess.

Comment: @Dom, I'm not sure I asked my question correctly. I did not mean the interval size between notes belonging to the same chord. I meant the positions on the scale that are selected to be in the chord. For example, if we take a hypothetical scale with: c, c#, d, d#, e, f, f# we would select the notes at positions I, III and V to be in a chord, i.e. c, d, e. These happen to have major seconds in between them. But the pattern I'm referring to is the one that just selects the three positions, regardless of the intervals between them.

Comment: In other words, the "note at position n, note at position n+2, note at position n+4 in the scale" pattern. Just to illustrate this pattern's independence from the intervals, take the example of the Hungarian minor scale, where making a chord from notes at positions IV, VI and VIII/(I) means we use a major second and major third. Does this position-based pattern have a name?

Comment: @hvth Its still by 3rds in any heptatonic scale which the chromatic scale is not. The hungarian scale even though it may look like a major 2nd it's spelled as a diminished 3rd as in C Hungarian minor scale  you would spell  that chord F#, Ab, C which is by thirds. Also building chords from the chromatic scale doesn't make sense as you lose all harmonic context which chords help provide.

Comment: To be more precise, it would be diatonic tertian harmony, since tertian harmony could include flats and sharps not included in the heptatonic scale.

Comment: @Dom Thanks, this clears it up for me a bit. So the only chord note-choosing pattern that exists in heptatonic scales is { POS(n), POS(n+2), POS(n+4) }. And everything must be expressed as a third somehow. So an interval of size 2 semitones becomes a "diminisher minor third". Would this be correct?

Comment: @JonathanM, is there a book or a similar resource you could recommend about harmonies other than diatonic tertian/heptatonic etc. ?